# How to check where a child node is contained within an ancestor node in pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have this list in HTML that dynamically changes based on the user's interactions due to some JS, which also changes a correlating list in JS that reflects the backend data: an array `listItems` where each `listItem` has instance variables `itemColor`, `itemSize`, and array `extraInfo`.

```
<div id="items-list">
    <div id="item-1" class="item">...</div>
    <div id="item-2" class="item">...</div>
    <div id="item-3" class="item">
        <div class="item-color">blue</div>
        <div class="item-size">big</div>
        <div class="extra-item-info-list">...</div>
</div>
```

Each item, based on the JS, will for certain have element `<div class = "item-color"></div>` and `<div class="item-size"></div>`. I want the user to be able to click on an item's attributes and interact with it so I can reflect changes in the JS data. Currently I'm placing event listeners on the nested `div` to detect a click on the event, but how do I check which `item` has been interacted with so I can change the correlating `listItem` in the JS? How can I see which `item` in `items-list` has been interacted with, knowing that a specific inner element has been interacted with? I have only one, pretty bad idea:

Check the children of the parent's parent and find the index of the parent with respect to the element: clicking on the third item's `item-color` will find index 2 because `item-3` is the 2nd index of `items-list`. Then I can find the second index of my array `listItems` and alter data there. However, this fails as a general function if the `div` structure changes, so I want a more general solution in possible, and in pure, vanilla JS: no JQuery.

Comment: You could put a reference to the DOM element in the array element. Then you can search for the DOM element in the array.

Comment: You can use the method `contains` to ask if on element is inside another. `elementA.contains(elementB) // true or false`

Comment: Does that require just looping through the `item-list` children in the DOM? I was also thinking that but I wanted to know if there was a more efficient way.

Comment: @protommxx sometimes loops are the way to go. Don't pre-optimise, instead optimise when performance actually becomes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

A loop works fine for your needs... Here is an example of how to loop over the class selector `.item` and check each list for children. If there are children, get the contents of that elements ID and iterate using a for loop, setting a variable to increment that will allow you to get the value of the child element using the key of the element within the list. Since your `.item` elements have id's, you can then use that to iterate over.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
const getElements = (el) => {
  el.forEach((item, key) => {
    // check for children with in the item element
    if (item.children[0] !== undefined) {
      // get the id of the current iteration of items children
      let elId = document.getElementById(item.id);
      console.log(`Element ID: ${elId.id}  -> has the following children:`);
      // let use .length of the amount of children to increment a key
      // and get the current items childrens values whatever they may be
      for (let i = 0; i < elId.children.length; i++) {
        console.log(`   CLASSNAME: ${elId.children[i].className}, text content -> ${elId.children[i].textContent}`)
      }
    }
  })
}

getElements(items);
```

```html
<div id="items-list">
  <div id="item-1" class="item">...</div>
  <div id="item-2" class="item">...</div>
  <div id="item-3" class="item">
    <div class="item-color">red</div>
    <div class="item-size">small</div>
    <div class="extra-item-info-list">...</div>
  </div>
  <div id="item-4" class="item">...</div>
  <div id="item-5" class="item">
    <div class="item-color">blue</div>
    <div class="item-size">big</div>
    <div class="extra-item-info-list">...</div>
  </div>
  <div id="item-6" class="item">...</div>
  <div id="item-7" class="item">
    <div class="item-color">green</div>
    <div class="item-size">medium</div>
    <div class="item-position">top</div>
  </div>
</div>
```